# With open as file along with for line in open

Tags: python, file-io

I have to read a line from a file do some computation and write to another file. 
I have done something like this

```
fd= open("abc.txt","w")
for line in open("test.txt","r"):
     Do something Here
     fd.write(modifiedline)
```

I have usually used with open and for open for line by line operations.
Is the above way which I am using ok to use or is there a better way where we use for open and with open together.

I am a student and wish to know more. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753899/python-best-way-to-read-a-file-and-break-out-the-lines-by-a-delimeter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Code**

```
with open("abc.txt", 'w') as outfi,open("test.txt","r") as infil:
    for line in infil:
        Do something Here
        outfi.write(modifiedline)
```