# How do I clean up empty lines in a configparser file?

Tags: python

I sometimes get an .ini file that looks like this after changing and deleting values:

```
[Section A]
x = 1
d = 2



[Section B]
a = 3
```

Is there an easy way to keep it clean and remove those blank lines between the sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can work:

```
lines = open("file").readlines()

n_lines = ["%s" % line for line in lines if line.strip()]

f = open("file", "w")
f.write("".join(n_lines))
f.close()
```

I use the list comprehension and create a new variable with the filter lines.

**EDIT**

If you can add a linebreak for each section, this maybe can work:

```
lines = open("file").readlines()

n_lines = ["\n%s" % line if "[Sect" in line else line for line in lines if line.strip()]

f = open("file", "w")
f.write("".join(n_lines).lstrip())
f.close()
```

**EDIT 2:**

I'm not sure... but

If your file is so large and the Python that you work is 3 version, maybe you can use this code for better performance:

```
def readfile(filepath): 
    with open(filepath, "r") as f: 
        for line in f:
            yield line

lines = readfile("file")

n_lines = ["\n%s" % line if "[Sect" in line else line for line in lines if line.strip()]

f = open("file", "w")
f.write("".join(n_lines).lstrip())
f.close()
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753899/python-best-way-to-read-a-file-and-break-out-the-lines-by-a-delimeter)

Comment: Why can't it be written without the %: n_lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip()]

Comment: Yes you can get the value of `line` without the `%`

Comment: Works great. It'd be perfect if it left one blank line after each section, but I can imagine that'd be a bit more complex. Maybe if it replaced each "[" with "\n[" except the first "["

Comment: I edited the question with another code that maybe can work with a linebreak in each section....

Comment: I removed the first linebreak with `lstrip()` in the `.write()`, you can test the code and confirm..

Comment: There's no need to use `readlines()` to read the entire file into memory at once since they can be iterated over a line-at-a-time: i.e. `f = open(...)`, `for line in f:`, `,,,`.

Comment: The better solution for a large file is this : 
`with open('file', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
      print line`
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246260/python-readlines-usage-and-efficient-practice-for-reading)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a strictly python solution, you can create a temp file, copy over the non empty lines, and then replace the file.

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
from os import close
from shutil import move

def replace(filename, name, new_value):
    fd, path = mkstemp()
    with open(path,'w') as tmpfile:
        with open(filename) as csv:
            for line in cvs:
                if line.strip()!="":
                    tmpfile.write(line)
    close(fd)
    move(path, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier using a tool like `grep`

```
$ grep -v "^\\s*$" foo > bar
```

but if you have to use Python then check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369440/how-to-delete-all-blank-lines-in-the-file-with-the-help-of-python).

Comment: It just seems weird that the configparser module doesn't keep the ini files tidy on its own.

Comment: Not that I have the skills to do so, but how hard would it be to add such a function to the official configparser library?

Comment: @Dima have a look at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/configparser.py#L904 ... probably a bit of work, but nothing too difficult.

Comment: @Dima you can fork it, make changes and post a merge request, see https://akrabat.com/the-beginners-guide-to-contributing-to-a-github-project/

Answer (score 0):

Just use sed:

`sed '/^$/d' myfile.ini`

works

Comment: I've never heard of sed. Is it part of the basic python library?

Comment: @Dima: it's a standard Unix tool, if you are on Linux or OS X it's installed by default.

Comment: To add to @MatteoItalia's comment, if you want sed (or grep for that matter) under windows you can install cygwin which gives you a Linux shell and various useful Linux commands.

Comment: I'd prefer to just use python because it doesn't seem like it'd be that hard to program. I was just wondering if configparser had a function I'm missing.

Comment: @TimGJ: personally I prefer GnuWin32, they are native ports of the coreutils and other stuff (unlike Cygwin, which actually provides a full POSIX emulation layer).

Comment: @Dima nowadays with dockerized and virtualized environments, developing on windows brings a lot of cool toys for the most basic linux container or VM.